# Java I/O - Simulate input for System.console()

Tags: java, junit, java-io

I am writing a JUnit for a program created in an exercise. That means the test needs to cover as many cases as possible and I don't have any influence on how certain things in the program are implemented. Also, the program runs an infinite loop where at one point, it requires the user to input something.
For the JUnit test I run the program in another `Thread` and simulate the user input from within the JUnit `Thread`.

So far, everything works fine if the program reads the user input from `System.in`, because this stream can easily replaced. But there's also the possiblity that the program interacts with `System.console()` which currently can not be covered by my test.

**Is there any possibility to simulate input for the `System.console()`, e.g. by replacing its input source with another stream?**

(NB: The JUnit test must use Java 6 without any external libraries (except JUnit and Hamcrest).)

Edit: Unfortunately, I can't change the classes of the program to test.

Comment: Your class' constructor has to accept a `Console` object, so you can *inject* it. Then in the test you will have to construct a *mock* instance of `Console` which you'll have to pass to the constructor.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev see my edit. Is there no other way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After looking at the JDK source code I found the the `Console` class is reading data from the standard input (`System.in`):

```
reader = new LineReader(StreamDecoder.forInputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(FileDescriptor.in), readLock, cs));
```

Where `FileDescriptor.in` is a constant pointing to the real standard input (`public static final FileDescriptor in = standardStream(0);`).
So even if you substitute `System.in` using `System.setIn()` the console class will still use the real standard input.

Your only option is to substitute the `Console` object with a **mock**.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to create an abstraction for the console as explained in [this post](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.fr/2010/09/java-systemconsole-ides-and-testing.html). And use this abstraction in the code instead of `System.console()`. Then you can mock the abstraction *you* control in the tests.

EDIT: 
Another solution which is more involved, is to modify the byte code of `System.console()` (or sun underlying classes) when it is loaded in the JVM. This is done by providing your own implementation of a `ClassLoader` and you can find information on how to do that. 
I'm not sure you want to go this rabbit hole...

Comment: Since I cannot influence what the actual program uses as console, the abstraction would be useless because the program would still use `System.console()` and not my custom console.
This would be different, if you could change the console used, like it is possible with `System.in` using `System.setIn()`

Answer (score 0):

On way i can think of use of mocking scanner class. For example

```
     int i = sc.nextInt();
```

now mock implementation will be called

```
 public void Scanner getScanner(){

   }


  // inject mock object for unit testing and in prod ,
      real object with input   stream from console
   public void Scanner setScanner(Scanner scanner){

    }
```

Comment: He is asking about `Console` not `Scanner`

Comment: but basically he wants to read stream which can be done from scanner too

Comment: I don't want to read a stream. I want to simulate input and therefore manipulate the **input source** of `System.console()`.