# system.console readPassword throws null pointer exception during junit test

Tags: java

I am using `System.console` and `readPassword()` method to read password from the user. The problem is that I cannot really initialize `System.console` object when running from IntelliJ (in my case it throws `NullPointerException` during JUnit tests). How should I approach that problem? I've seen that people are using `Scanner` or `BufferedReader` to overcome that problem, but neither of these two can not nicely hide entered password like `readPassword()`. Generally speaking my program is intended to run from command line (JAR) and it does nicely but these unit tests are failing from IntelliJ.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29431697/java-i-o-simulate-input-for-system-console

Comment: Why not compile it differently for unit testing?  Perhaps read from the environment or a file, in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care if the password is visible when you run your code in the IDE or during unit tests, then the [Console with Fallback](https://codeberg.org/marc.nause/console-with-fallback) library may be a sufficient solution for you. If the environment provides a console (in the command line), this is used. If the environment does not provide a console (unit tests), a fallback based on `System.out` and `System.in` is used.